# Math in highcharts to change units?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been making a website to display weather data: http://erbweather.com/US.html?station=NYC&year=2016.  Currently all of my temperature data is in Fahrenheit, but I'd like to add an option to show it in Celsius.  The data is read from a text file.  Is there a way to covert the values to Celsius after reading it from the file?  The lines to read the data look like this:

```
$.get("data/QCLCD/" + year + "/daily_data_" + station_code + "_" + year + ".csv", function(csv) {
  $('#container1').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    data: {
      csv: csv,
      startColumn:0,
      endColumn: 4
    },
    ...
```

The equation I want to add is a simple one: TEMP_C = (5/9)*(TEMP_F-32).  Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: What does the csv object look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve expected effect using **update()** functions on Series and Chart objects for example.

First, you should calculate all values from Farenheit to Celcius. I used for that code below:

```
const oldSeriesData = []
const fToCel = temp => Math.round( (temp - 32)/1.8 ) // Converting function

// Create array with old data values
chart.series.forEach(series => { oldSeriesData.push(series.userOptions.data) })

// Create array with calculated values
const newSeriesData = oldSeriesData.map( subarray =>  {
    return subarray.map( elem => {
        return [elem[0], (elem[1] !== null) ? fToCel(elem[1]) : null]
    });
})
```

If you will calculate new values, then you've to update a chart series data with those new calculated values, so I did that using **update()**:

```
// Update series with Celsius data values
chart.series.forEach((series, i) => {
    series.update({
        data: newSeriesData[i]
    })
})

// Update yAxis title and tooltip suffix
chart.update({
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
    }
})
```

Here is the complete [JSFiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/sdx83yun/)

API Reference:
[Chart.update()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update)
[Series.update()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update)

Comment: Fantastic, that works like a charm.  I still have to do some adjustments, but I've added this to the website: http://erbweather.com/US.html?station=NYC&year=2016.  Two questions:

Comment: 1) I added a second button to switch the data back to it's original Fahrenheit units.  At the moment it simply refreshes the page.  Is there a more elegant way to return to the original figure?

2) For some reason, my tooltip doesn't update from F to C, even though a specified a new tooltip.  As far as I can tell, I changed it exactly as you did.  Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Of course there is. The way is the same like in my previous example, so you should update the series object once again, but with Farenheit values data.
2) After reviewing your code, I can say that you are using Highcharts v5.0.0 version, and most certainly that is general reason of this kind of problems. Please try to use newest release of Highcharts, and problem will disappear.

I prepared next example for you, where i implement two buttons to change the chart data:
http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/7q0a16g5/